# Combining regular expressions in bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to compare a string with the $ character, followed by either s or t and a range of numbers. but the range is different for each letter.
for example if it is an **s** it can be followed by numbers between 0-7 and if it is a **t** it can be followed by numbers between 0-9.

What I managed to write a part of the if statement to compare it, but I couldn't figure out how to include different ranges for each letter

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="test1.txt"
check(){
    while read -r line; do
      a=( $line )
      for i in "${a[@]:1}"; do
         if [[ "$i" == \$[st]* ]]; then
             echo "$i"
         fi
      done
    done < "$input"
}
check
```

Instead of using * I want to specify for **s** that it can only be followed by numbers between 0-7 and **t** can only be followed by numbers 0-9.
I tried using this:

```
if [[ "$i" == \$(s[0-7]*|t[0-9]*) ]]; then
```

but I got this error:

```
./test.sh: line 9: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('                                         ./test.sh: line 9: syntax error near `\$(s'                                                                             ./test.sh: line 9: `if [[ "$i" == \$(s[0-7]*|t[0-9]*) ]]; then'
```

Comment: Note that `a=( $line )` is a dangerous practice for the reasons described in [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) (while the pitfall refers to command substitutions, unquoted parameter expansions behave identically for purposes thereof) -- better to make it `while read -r -a a; do` and have `read` split the words of your line into array elements itself.

Answer (score 7):

`=~` is used for regex matching, not `==`. Correct that and use a pipe (`|`) in your regex, which means **OR**.

```
if [[ $i =~ \$(s[0-7]*|t[0-9]*) ]]
```

Comment: @David, also note that `=~` is a **bash**-specific feature, so you cannot run your code like `sh ./myscript`

Comment: Personally, I would use `[$]` rather than `\$` -- it's a bit more robust across different quoting contexts/styles -- but that's a trivial quibble; this is a good solution either way.

Comment: If you really *want* to use `==`, you can use the extended pattern `[$]@(s*([0-7])|t*([0-9]))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing a script with a loop for this? It can simply be done using a `grep`, as you can see in this example:

```
Prompt>cat test1.txt
s1
s8
t1
t8
Prompt> grep -E "s[0-7]|t[0-9]" test1.txt
s1
t1
t8
```

Explanation:

`s[0-7]` means the letter "s", followed by any digit from 0 to 7.
`t[0-9]` means the letter "t", followed by any digit from 0 to 9.

`grep -E` means "Extended regular expression".

`A|B` in the regular expression means `The expression should contain A OR B` (which is exactly the "extended" part of the regular expression).

Comment: FYI, your post was incorrectly flagged as "low quality". It has been handled accordingly. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22597487).